# Android app SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

I have an Android App that needs to connect to a server that has a SSL certificate.

I'm new to this. Can you please tell me the steps to trust that certificate?

I'm using Retrofit library for my Rest Client

Comment: I dont know retrofit, but normally you can make a restcall just like you would to an ip address like this `https://www.myapp.com/api/resource`

Comment: I think OP is talking about self-signed certificates. The magic word is 'Public Key Pinning' then. But **please** know what you are doing, OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [previously posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309738/android-app-ssl-certificate/35309846#35309846) with a proper trust store:

```
public class RestModule {
     private RestAdapter mRestAdapter;
     private RaasService mRaasService;
     private String mAccessToken;

     public RestModule(final Context context, final String endPoint)
     {
          init(context, endPoint);
     }
     public RestModule(final Context context, final String endPoint, final String accessToken) {
          mAccessToken = accessToken;
          init(context, endPoint);
     }
     public void init(final Context context, final String endPoint) {
          final MyPreferences preference = MyPreferences.getInstance();
          final RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                  .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                      @Override
                      public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                          if (mAccessToken == null) {
                              mAccessToken = preference.getCurrentAccountAccessToken();
                          }
                          requestFacade.addHeader("secretToken", mAccessToken);
                          requestFacade.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                      }
                  })
                  .setEndpoint(endPoint);
          builder.setClient(new OkClient(getPinnedOkHttpClient(context)));
          mRestAdapter = builder.build();

     }

     private static OkHttpClient getPinnedOkHttpClient(Context context) {
          try {
              final SSLContext sslContext = getSslContext(context);
              sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
              // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
              final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
              OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
              okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
              okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                      return true;
                  }
              });
              okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              return okHttpClient;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
     }

     private SSLContext getSslContext(Context context) throws Exception {
         KeyStore trustStore = loadTrustStore(context);
         String algotithmName = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
         TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algotithmName);
         trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
         SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
         sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
         return sslContext;
     }

     private KeyStore loadTrustStore(Context context) throws Exception {
         KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
         InputStream trustStoreStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open("trust.bks");
         trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "password".toCharArray());
         return trustStore;
     }

     public RaasService getService() {
          if (mRaasService == null) {
              mRaasService = mRestAdapter.create(RaasService.class);
          }
          return mRaasService;
     }
}
```

You have to put the server certificate in a BKS keystore and put in a file called `trust.bks` in the `assets` folder, using `password` as the trust store's password. Having a (publicly) known password in the code is no problem in **this** case, because there is not a single byte of secrecy stored in a trust store, holding only a publicly known server certificate.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515314/generating-a-bks-keystore-and-storing-app-key) tells you how to create a BKS keystore from your server certificate.